# Wildcards in php's strpos function

Tags: php, wildcard, strpos

I'm looking for some wildcards to the `strpos` function similar to those used in `preg_replace` or `preg_match` but I can't find any, here is an idea:

```
<?php
if (strpos("The black\t\t\thorse", "black horse") === false)
  echo "Text NOT found.";
else
  echo "Text found.";
?>
```

Here the result will be: `Text NOT found.`

Now I want to use one wildcard to omit spaces or horizontal tab like below:

```
<?php
if (strpos("The black\t\t\thorse", "black/*HERE THE WILDCARD*/horse") === false)
  echo "Text NOT found.";
else
  echo "Text found.";
?>
```

And here the idea is that the result is: `Text found.`

Does anyone know something about ?

Comment: You can't find it because it doesn't exist, `strpos` only does exact matching. If you want wildcards, you have to use regular expressions.

Comment: Well, if you need wild cards, then why not use `preg_match` instead?

Comment: I'm using strpos because i'm trying to find a block of code of 3 lines into one file and replace by another block of text, do you know some function to make this easy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strpos() doesn't match patterns, if you want to match patterns you have to use preg_match() this should work for your situation.

```
<?php
    if (preg_match('/black[\s]+horse/', "The black\t\t\thorse"))
      echo "Text found.";
    else
      echo "Text not found.";
?>
```

Comment: I'm using `strpos` because i'm trying to find a block of code of 3 lines into one file and replace by another block of text, do you know some function to make this easy ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the first occurrence of the match then you can use the PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag:

```
preg_match('/black\shorse/i', "The black\t\t\thorse", $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
var_dump($matches);
```

will result in

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "black horse" [1]=> int(4) } }
```

where $matches[0][1] is your position